# Tiny numbers '1' and '2' just above the select all button

Tags: microsoft-excel

What are the two tiny numbers above the Select All button in the upper left? I can't seem to get rid of them.

[image: tiny numbers]

Comment: it is [Grouping](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff) indicators.

Comment: to get rid of it you `ungroup` (use excel search feature)

Answer (score 1):

You have [Grouped Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff) in your worksheet.

Grouped rows will look like this with the numbers horizontal:

[image]

But grouping columns will make the numbers show vertical as in your image.

Clicking the numbers will expand or contract those levels of grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Select all Worksheet- go to **Data**- select **Ungroup** option and choose **Columns**:

[image]